# Selecting rows in a Dataset

Tags: dataset

I'm struggling to get certain rows from a Dataset.  Here's the set:

```
plateData = ResourceData["Large Global Plate Boundaries"]
```

I'd like to do something like this, which obviously isn't working.  "Get the rows from the dataset that include "America" in the name.

```
Select[plateData, StringContainsQ[#Name, "American" | "american"] &]
```

I'd like to think their is a way do do this simply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At its heart, the issue is that some of the entries in that data set have `Missing["NotAvailable"]` for the `"Name"` parameter. [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) only applies selection criteria until it hits an error, at which point it simply throws a [`Failure`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Failure.html) object (I believe this is a fail-safe to keep from crashing the kernel / FE with compounded errors in big data).

So simply add a "not missing" check to the `Select`:

```
plateData[
  Select[
   ! MissingQ@#["Name"] && 
     StringContainsQ[#["Name"], "American" | "american"] & 
   ]
  ] // Length

441
```